# How would you use asyncpg with FastAPI to map returned values from a select query to pydantic models for output and validation?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic, asyncpg

I want to use FastAPI without an ORM (using asyncpg) and map the returned values from a select query to a pydantic model. This way the returned values are validated with pydantic and the response that is returned is structured like the pydantic model/schema.

I’ve tried looking for documentation on this but it’s pretty hard to find/not clear. I’d appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Every pydantic model [inherits a couple of utility helpers to create objects](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions). One is `parse_obj` which takes a dict and creates the model object from that.

> `parse_obj`: this is very similar to the `__init__` method of the model, except it takes a dict rather than keyword arguments. If the object passed is not a dict a ValidationError will be raised.

From the example on the linked section above:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'John Doe'
    signup_ts: datetime = None


m = User.parse_obj({'id': 123, 'name': 'James'})
print(m)
#> id=123 signup_ts=None name='James'
```

You might be able to give `parse_obj` a Record directly since it implements dict-like accessors, so just try it and see if it works. If not you can use `dict(<row record from asyncpg>)` to convert the record to an actual dict.

Comment: Thanks! For the most part I have mapping and validation working now. I’m still working out a strange side effect in terms of the response model in that it displays all fields versus specified fields in the output model (as per docs: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/ )